# Laravel 5.4 - Validation not working

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-validation

Am I doing something wrong with the validation

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use Validator;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class SignupController extends Controller
{
  public function postSignup(Request $request)
  {
      if($this->validate($request, [
          'first_name' => 'required|max:255'
      ])){
          echo json_encode(array('TRUE'));
      }else{
          echo json_encode(array('FALSE'));
      }
  }
}
```

The request data is right...

But the validator always return null... and the return json is the FALSE

Comment: Check out how to write Laravel validation from [Laravel Validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#manually-creating-validators)

Comment: `validate` does not return true or false. It throws an exception when it fails and returns nothing if it succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

validate does not return true or false. It throws an exception when it fails and returns nothing if it succeeds.

thank you @apokryfos